# Is it correct to say "...which of the following do you like or not like?"

Tags: grammar, synonyms, questions

Is it correct to say

> "...which of the following do you like or not like?"

In specific, I'm interested in the "...do you like or **not like**?" part.
I would rather say "which do you like and which don't", or would paraphrase it another way, but maybe it's OK to say it as it's stated in the question?

Comment: The intent of the question may be understandable but the “. . . or not like” is not necessary and could lead to an ambiguous answer if on being asked the question someone merely listed the items without a qualifier  and caused you to ask a further question “do you like or not like items you listed ?”

Comment: *Which of the following do you like or not like* is grammatically correct.  However — questionnaire-wise — I'm having a hard time imagining how likes and dislikes submitted together could be parsed as data points.